# Javascript validation with default field value

Tags: javascript, validation

newbie here. I need some help.

I am using a pre-written javascript form validator for my website but the thing is, it is not designed for fields with **default value**. So the problem is the validator is considering the value "Name" and "Message" to be valid and the message goes through without any error message.

I did some research and saw some suggestions but with very little knowledge in javascript i don't know how to implement them or how to create another set of validation rules.

By the way i am using free contact form from [http://www.faridhadi.com/][1]

Below is the script i am working on:

I hope you guys can help me! Thanks!

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contactForm #submit').click(function() {
        // Fade in the progress bar
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').hide();
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Sending&hellip;');
        $('#contactForm #formProgress').fadeIn();

        // Disable the submit button
        $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        // Clear and hide any error messages
        $('#contactForm .formError').html('');

        // Set temaprary variables for the script
        var isFocus=0;
        var isError=0;

        // Get the data from the form
        var name=$('#contactForm #name').val(); 
        var email=$('#contactForm #email').val();
        var subject=$('#contactForm #subject').val();
        var message=$('#contactForm #message').val();

        // Validate the data
        if(name=='') {
            $('#contactForm #errorName').html('This is a required field.');
            $('#contactForm #name').focus();
            isFocus=1;
            isError=1;
        }
        if(email=='') {
            $('#contactForm #errorEmail').html('This is a required field.');
            if(isFocus==0) {
                $('#contactForm #email').focus();
                isFocus=1;
            }
            isError=1;
        } else {
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            if(reg.test(email)==false) {
                $('#contactForm #errorEmail').html('Invalid email address.');
                if(isFocus==0) {
                    $('#contactForm #email').focus();
                    isFocus=1;
                }
                isError=1;
            }
        }
        if(message=='') {
            $('#contactForm #errorMessage').html('This is a required field.');
            if(isFocus==0) {
                $('#contactForm #message').focus();
                isFocus=1;
            }
            isError=1;
        }

        // Terminate the script if an error is found
        if(isError==1) {
            $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
            $('#contactForm #formProgress').hide();

            // Activate the submit button
            $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");

            return false;
        }

        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });

        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/submit-form-ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(msg) {

                //alert(msg);

                // Check to see if the mail was successfully sent
                if(msg=='Mail sent') {
                    // Update the progress bar
                    $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('<img src="images/ajax-complete.gif" /> Message sent.').delay(2000).fadeOut(400);

                    // Clear the subject field and message textbox
                    $('#contactForm #subject').val('');
                    $('#contactForm #message').val('');
                } else {
                    $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
                    alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');
                }

                // Activate the submit button
                $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");
            },
            error: function(ob,errStr) {
                $('#contactForm #formProgress').html('');
                alert('There was an error sending your email. Please try again.');

                // Activate the submit button
                $('#contactForm #submit').attr("disabled", "");
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use HTML5 [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute) attribute for your "default value". To support all the browsers you can use [jQuery watermark](https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-Watermark) plugin that poly fills the older browser to support `placeholder`.

For validation also it's better to use widely used [jQuery Validator](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plug-in

Answer (score 0):

If by default you mean the initial `value="No Subject"` you can modify assigning the variables  to account for that value if the input is empty;

```
var name = $('#contactForm #name');
name = $.trim(name.val()) || name.prop("defaultValue");
...
var email = ....
```